# Rails error_messages helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a very common piece of code

```
<% form_for :blah... do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
First name: <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />
....
<% end %>
```

`error_messages` is a helper method but I am having a hard time finding the documentation for it, why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found them here: error_messages have same params as [error_messages_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/ActiveRecordHelper/error_messages_for).

In Rails 3 however, error_messages and error_messages_for have been deprecated and [have been moved out to a plugin](https://github.com/joelmoss/dynamic_form).

Comment: Thanks for the info but how did you know that both have the same params? That's the part that irks me, I don't see any clear reference to that effect.

Comment: You're right. I couldn't find any doc for that. Having a look at the code though, make it clear for me: http://bit.ly/dyXaYs . Seems that all error_messages is doing is call error_messages_for with the options received as params. Hope this helps.