# error_messages_for is deprecated in ruby - how do I find the replacement?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am reading an old book (2008) to learn ruby and it is for rails 2.0.2.

I have decided to use Rails 3 to find out the differences between the ruby back then to what it is now. Most of it has been good so far and I have been easily been able to find and correct the differences.

The problem I am having now, is that the code is using a deprecated function `error_messages_for` and upon looking at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/ActiveRecordHelper/error_messages_for I cannot find a replacement or any way to show me what the new way is. Can someone help me find the new way to use `error_messages_for` and how I should go about finding the new way to do things and the way to discover the new best practices etc.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a newer book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [f.error_messages in Rails 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873190/f-error-messages-in-rails-3-0)
- [Rails error_messages helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025057/rails-error-messages-helper)
- http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails3-error-messages-for-replacement
- http://ariejan.net/2010/12/15/why-did-errormessagesfor-disappear-from-rails-3/
- https://gist.github.com/1113828

Just the top 5 links found searching Google for "rails error_messages_for rails 3".

That said, you really should use an up-to-date book. Even the latest free Rails tutorials are covering Rails 3.

Comment: Not all books are updated