# undefined method `errors' for #<Array:0x7fa1cbbbde50>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my **edit_scheme.rhtml** file in which i'm getting this error.

```
<%=stylesheet_link_tag 'showpage'%>
<%=stylesheet_link_tag 'easy'%>
<%= error_messages_for 'scheme' %>
<% form_tag({:action =>'updatescheme', :id =>@scheme},:multipart=>true) do %>
  <!--[form:document]-->
  <h2>Edit Scheme</h2>
  <%@role = Role.find(:first, :conditions =>["role_name=?",'Help Desk'])%>

<%= render :partial=> 'schemeform'%>
<!--[endform:document]-->

<tr style="text-align:right;">
<td></td>
<td> Status:</td>  
  <td> <%=radio_button :scheme, :status, "Active"%>Active 
  <%=radio_button :scheme, :status, "In-Active"%>In-Active</td>
</tr>
<p align="center" style="padding-top:10px;">
  <%= submit_tag 'Edit' ,:style=>"padding:2px;"%>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <%if session[:role]=="Administrator"%>
  <%= link_to 'Back',:action=>'scheme_search'%>
  <%end%>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The error refers to this line

```
<%= error_messages_for 'scheme' %>
```

What I'm Missing? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please add more information.

Comment: While am trying to edit am getting the above error.

Comment: It's still definitely not enough information.

Comment: @Marek Lipka I edited my post to provide some additional information.please tell me if you want more information

Comment: @user3083044 what version of Rails are you using? see this: "error_messages_for is deprecated in ruby" http://stackoverflow.com/a/11435994/1076207

Comment: @awesome I'm using Rails 2.2 and Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: @Nageswar Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list all errors for i.e. a product from a form:

```
<% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
```

You should also test are there any errors at all.

```
<% if @product.errors.any? %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

This should work with a collection too.

Comment: if you had a collection of products? no it wouldn't work, not without iterating over each product (which is the part the asker is missing, I think)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `:object` param as the second arg:

```
<%= error_messages_for 'scheme', :object => @scheme %>
```

I found this comment in the source of Rails 2.2 above the `error_messages_for` method:

```
# If the objects cannot be located as instance variables, you can add an extra <tt>:object</tt> parameter which gives the actual
# object (or array of objects to use):
#
#   error_messages_for 'user', :object => @question.user
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c6cb5a5ab00ac9e857e5b2757d2bce6a5ad14b32/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/active_record_helper.rb#L162